# Regex matching extra characters

Tags: regex

using: [this tool to evaluate my expression](https://regex101.com/)

My test string: "Little" Timmy (tim) McGraw

my regex: 
    ^[()"]|.["()]

It looks like I'm properly catching the characters I want but my matches are including whatever character comes just before the match.  I'm not sure what, or if anything, I'm doing wrong to be catching the preceding characters like that?  The goal is to capture characters we don't want in the name field of one of our systems.

Comment: What about simply using `[()"]`? Ultimately, however, it would be much easier to create a negated set that determines which characters **are valid** rather than those that are *invalid*. This approach would get you something like `[^\w ]`

Comment: Unfortunately our data set has lots of names with ' and at least one name featuring a $ so situation sort of makes having a blanket exclusion impractical.  These specific characters break downstream systems for us though and definitely need to be excluded.

Comment: If you can post some of these examples we can better help you

Comment: Unfortunately the source system is FERPA protected so I'm pretty sure I can't share actual names out of it but your answer in your first comment worked perfectly and taught me a thing I didn't know about regex. If you can put it in a reply/answer I'd mark it as such.  You rock!

Comment: You could even post fake strings that mimic the same idea of the original strings so as to not post any sensitive information. I've added an answer below. With more samples given I (or someone else) could give you a more appropriate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

Your current regex `^[()"]|.["()]` says the following:

- `^[()"]|.["()]` Match either of the following

  - `^[()"]` Match the following

    - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
    - `[()"]` Match any character present in the list `()"`
  - `.["()]` Match the following

    - `.` Match any character (this is the issue you were having)
    - `["()]` Match any character present in the list `"()`

---

### Code

You can actually shorten your regex to just `[()"]`.

Ultimately, however, it would be much easier to create a negated set that determines which characters are valid rather than those that are invalid. This approach would get you something like `[^\w ]`. This means match anything not present in the set. So match any non-word and non-space characters (in your sample string this will match the symbols `()"` since they are not in the set).

Comment: Your answer led me to exactly what I was missing.  I was over complicating the expression by thinking I had to tell it to do things it didn't need to do.  That is, by default it would capture the individual characters.  I didn't need to tell it to look at them individual or to hit the first character.  Thanks!  you rock.